# CSS: Force float to do a whole new line

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a bunch of `float: left` elements and some are SLIGHTLY bigger than others. I want the newline to break and have the images float all the way to the left instead of getting stuck on a bigger element.

Here is the page I'm talking about : [link](http://www.stdicon.com/gartoon/)

If they are all the same size if works beautifully : [link](http://www.stdicon.com/crystal/)

Thanks! (I'd rather not get into javascript or server side scripting if I don't have to)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Well, if you really need to use `float` declarations, you have two options:

1. Use `clear: left` on the leftmost items - the con is that you'll have a fixed number of columns
2. Make the items equal in `height` - either by script or by hard-coding the height in the CSS

Both of these are limiting, because they work around how floats work. However, you may consider using `display: inline-block` instead of `float`, which will achieve the similar layout. You can then adjust their alignment using `vertical-align`.

Comment: This is not correct. There is a satisfactory CSS answer. See @David Davepermen Spörri 's response.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I've updated the answer to reflect this approach, too.

Answer (score 64):

I fixed it by removing `float:left`, and adding `display:inline-block` instead. Haven't used it for images, but should work fine, there, too.

Comment: This is the correct answer in my opinion (for the general case at least). I'm not using images in my case though (if this makes a difference, you can always wrap your image in a `<div>` or `<li>` to abstract away).  Be aware that you may also want to use `vertical-align:top`. Default is to align on the bottom, which can look a bit odd if the boxes are of significantly different size (which again, they are in my case).

Comment: I had a similar issue and `display:inline-table` worked best for me; thx for the hint :)

Comment: I fail to see how this solves the problem. What about white-space? `inline-block` is only a good method when you minify your html.

Answer (score 6):

Use `display:inline-block`

You may also find `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align:middle` useful.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did.  Seems to work in forcing a new line, but I'm not an html/css guru by any measure.

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap them in a div and give the div a set width (the width of the widest image + margin maybe?) and then float the divs.  Then, set the images to the center of their containing divs.  Your margins between images won't be consistent for the differently sized images but it'll lay out much more nicely on the page.

Comment: How will forcing a width stop them from sticking, isn't it a height problem? And how can I calculate the height of the images without coding?

Comment: you can also apply a height to the containing div.  Just get the height in pixels of the longest image and make that the height.  You can get the height in pixels by opening your image in photoshop or fireworks or whatever image utility you prefer.  In the link you provided, the longest container seems to be 140px;  anything smaller than that is sticking.

Comment: hmm, all of my images are dynamically generated, so the heights will vary. I'm guess I'm down to doing javascript...

Comment: no, not the images, the height of the div that contains them.  Put this height in your CSS.

Comment: right, but how do I calculate that height? I have many "sets" that all have different images with different heights : http://www.stdicon.com/

Comment: you don't need to calculate the height.  Wrap each image in a div and set the height of that div to 140px; - if 140px still causes images to get stuck then try increasing it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `.icons div {width:160px; height:130px;}` will work out very nicely

Hope it will help

Comment: Sadly all of my pages have different sized images, like that will make http://www.stdicon.com/tango/ look quite ugly :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post and the links are no longer valid but because it came up early in a search I was doing I thought I should comment to help others understand the problem better.

By using float you are asking the browser to arrange your controls automatically.  It responds by wrapping when the controls don't fit the width for their specified float arrangement.  float:left, float:right or clear:left,clear:right,clear:both.

So if you want to force a bunch of float:left items to float uniformly into one left column then you need to make the browser decide to wrap/unwrap them at the same width.  Because you don't want to do any scripting you can wrap all of the controls you want to float together in a single div.  You would want to add a new wrapping div with a class like:

```
.LeftImages{
    float:left;
}
```

html

```
<div class="LeftImages">   
  <img...>   
  <img...> 
</div>
```

This div will automatically adjust to the width of the largest image and all the images will be floated left with the div all the time (no wrapping).

If you still want them to wrap you can give the div a width like width:30% and each of the images the float:left; style.  Rather than adjust to the largest image it will vary in size and allow the contained images to wrap.